# How do I theme LXDE like PIXEL?

Tags: raspbian, lxde, pixel

I really like the new PIXEL theme for Raspbian. How can I install this theme on Lubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest Raspberry Pi image from their website and flash it. Once you've done that, you can transfer the icon packs (no icons for everything) and themes to your distro and place them in your `~/.themes` and `~/.icons` folders. Use `lxappearance` and pick PiX icons and themes and you're done. If you can't find where they are, just do a quick file search for PiX.